# Python Spell Check With Suggestions

Tags: python, spell-checking

I have a program that I'm working on that takes an input and checks it to see if it spelled correctly with a dictionary inside of a file.  However, I want to return a suggestion or two as well of what the person means. Any suggestions of how to do this?  I have found some modules that can do it, but not for a specific dictionary from a file.  Any help is appreciated!!

Here is what I have now:

```
def getDictionary():
  theDictionary = open("theDictionary.txt", "r")
  dictionaryList = []
  for eachLine in theDictionary:
    splitLines = eachLine.split()
    dictionaryList.append(splitLines[0])
  theDictionary.close()
  return dictionaryList

def spellChecker(theFile, theDictionary):
  lowerItems = theFile.lower()
  wordList = lowerItems.split()
  wrongList = []
  for item in wordList:
    if item not in theDictionary:
        result = False
        wrongList.append(item)

    else:
        result = True
        wrongItem = ""
  return (result, wrongList)

def main():
  theDictionary = getDictionary()
  theText = getFile()
  theInput = input("Input some words here:")
  result, wrongList=spellChecker(theInput,theDictionary)
  if result:
    print("There are no spelling errors in the sentence!  Hooray!")
else:
    if len(wrongList) == 1:
        print('There is a spelling error in the sentence!  The word that is wrong is "' +     str(wrongList) + '".')
    elif len(wrongList) > 1:
        print('There are some spelling errors in the sentence!  The words that are wrong are"' + str(wrongList) + '".')

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/difflib.html) module in the Standard Library. It allows you to do approximate string matching, which seems to be what you want.

It really does not matter if your dictionary is inside a file or not, since you are loading it into a list anyway. Maybe have a look at the [get_close_matches()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) method in the said module.